# Remove duplicate content issue using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My `.htaccess` file looks likes this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?pg=$1 [L]
```

When a non-file or non-dir url is requested, it works fine.

But if `index.php?pg=(pagename)` is requested, it also works which can possibly lead to duplicate content issue.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this can lead to duplicate content.
And, yes, it is possible to avoid it.

This solution redirects old url to new url equivalent, for instance `http://website.com/index.php?pg=get/my/page/please.html` to `http://website.com/get/my/page/please.html`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?pg=([^&\s]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pg=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Pls explain the use of %1. Is it corresponds to %{THE_REQUEST} ?

Comment: `%1` is a backreference (first group matched, that's why it is `1` here) that contains data captured in a `RewriteCond`. In this case, `%1` contains the value of the parameter `pg` from your query string. Why using `THE_REQUEST` ? Because thanks to that we can make the difference between a server request and a simple user request, in order to avoid any redirection loop